# Workaround setDate for PreparedStatement in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, prepared-statement, deprecated

I have a method with a PreparedStatement

```
    public static boolean TSTHolidayPrepMapper(PreparedStatement st, TSTObject item, MapperType type) throws SQLException
{
    TSTHoliday hol = (TSTHoliday) item;
    int id = 1;
    if (type != MapperType.DELETE)
    {
        st.setString(id++, hol.getCountry());
        st.setString(id++, hol.getCommodity());
        st.setString(id++, hol.getMarketArea());
        st.setString(id++, hol.getMarketPlace());
        st.setString(id++, hol.getName());

        st.setDate(id++, hol.getCalenderDate());
    }
    if (type != MapperType.INSERT)
        st.setInt(id++, hol.getId());

    return true;
}
```

which expects a Date type object at `st.setDate(id++, hol.getCalenderDate())` but the getCalenderDate() method delivers an object of a class which I have created myself called TSTLocalDate

```
public class TSTLocalDate extends TSTObject
{
public int year;
public int month;
public int day;

public TSTLocalDate()
{
    this.year = 1900;
    this.month = 1;
    this.day = 1;
}

public TSTLocalDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
}

public String toString()
{
    String val = "" + year + "-" + TSTStringFormatter.getIntWithLeadingZeros(month, 2) + "-" + TSTStringFormatter.getIntWithLeadingZeros(day, 2);

    return val;
}
}
```

I have thought about two different solutions

1. I have tried to convert my TSTLocalDate calenderDate to a Date calenderDate but it seems like it does not work well since the Date classes methods are deprecated

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation"})
   public Date tstlocaldateToDate(TSTLocalDate tstlocaldate) throws ParseException {       

   Date date = new Date(0);

   date.setYear(tstlocaldate.year);
   date.setMonth(tstlocaldate.month);
   date.setDate(tstlocaldate.day);

   Log.info(date.getYear());
   return date;
   }
   ```
2. I tried to find a way to declare an own data type for the PreparedStatement so that I can pass calenderDate as TSTLocalDate object to the PreparedStatement like `st.setTSTLocalDate(id++, hol.getCalenderDate());` but sadly I did not find a way how to do it.

I would prefer the second solution but I am open for other solutions too.

Comment: Do you really need the `TSTLocalDate` class? Can you use something like a `java.sql.Timestamp` instead?

Comment: @JonK - Or `LocalDate`.

Comment: Why have you created a custom type `TSTLocalDate` when there is `java.time.LocalDate` and the possibility of doing `Date date = Date.valueOf(LocalDate localDate);`? **See the answer given by @T.J.Crowder**

Comment: Sadly I have to use the TSTLocalDate class because this is a requirement I got with this task

Comment: To be clear, my answer shows how to use `LocalDate` to go from `TSTLocalDate` to `java.sql.Date` for the `PreparedStatement`, it doesn't recommend using `LocalDate` *instead* of `TSTLocalDate` (though of course, if that were an option...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder your solution works very well for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...but it seems like it does not work well since the Date classes methods are deprecated.

If you look at the JavaDoc's deprecation message, [it tells you what to do](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#setYear(int)):

> **Deprecated.**
>
> As of JDK version 1.1, **replaced by `Calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1900)`.**

*(my emphasis on the second paragraph)*

So the old way would be to:

- Get a `Calendar` using [`getInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()) or one of its overloads.
- Use the methods of `Calendar` to set the correct date.
- Use the bizarrely-named `getTime` to get a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) instance for that date.
- Use the `java.sql.Date` constructor, passing in the `Date`'s `getTime()`.
- Use that with your `PreparedStatement`.

That said, with a modern JDK, you'd probably want to go through the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, probably [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), to do the conversion instead as it's a fair bit simpler. Then you'd use [`java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDate)):

```
ps.setDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(
    tstlocaldate.year,
    tstlocaldate.month,
    tstlocaldate.dayOfMonth
));
```